# Angular material button-toggle-group

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a button toggle group. The functionality is that when I click a particular item, the background color should be changed. When I toggle one of the buttons, the newly selected button's color should change and the old one should return back to the default background color. Here is my code:

**HTML**

```html
<mat-button-toggle-group name="fontStyle" aria-label="Font Style" vertical >
  <mat-button-toggle value="bold" (click)="changeColor()" mat-button-toggle [style.background-color]="color">Bold</mat-button-toggle>
  <mat-button-toggle value="italic" (click)="changeColor()" mat-button-toggle [style.background-color]="color">Italic</mat-button-toggle>
  <mat-button-toggle value="underline"(click)="changeColor()" mat-button-toggle [style.background-color]="color">Underline</mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```

**TypeScript**

```ts
export class ButtonToggleOverviewExample {
  color:string;

  changeColor(){ 
    this.color='green';
  }

}
```

The problem is that once a button is toggled it remains in the same color as clicked one.

Comment: each button has different color??

Comment: No.All have same color. default color: white, on-click:green

Comment: check my solution. on demo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pkshes)

in `style.css`

```
.mat-button-toggle-checked{
  background-color: green;
}
```